# How can I input Lshift and Rshift at c# form?

Tags: c#, input

```
      private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

      switch(e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.LShiftKey:
                Player1_Score.Text = player1.Player1_Score_Pick().ToString();
                break;
            case Keys.RShiftKey:
                Player2_Score.Text = player2.Player2_Score_Pick().ToString();
                break;

        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            Player1_Score.Text = player1.Player1_Score_Pick().ToString();
        }
```

Other keys are working but Lshift and Rshift is not working. I tried many other things ,but enter and Lshift and Rshift etc... didn't work. What can I do?

Comment: What does "working" and "not working" mean?

Comment: Player1_Score.Text = player1.Player1_Score_Pick().ToString(); is not working at case keys.LShiftKey: and Rshift

Comment: Check out the [Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_KeyEventArgs_Modifiers) property of the `KeyEventArgs` parameter.

Comment: @discoda - I understand that that code isn't working, but what does it do that doesn't work and what would it look like if it worked?

Comment: Some numbers will change if that code work.